# reverse a string value within a dict in python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a program in python 3 that reads in JSON strings and modifies them. I need to search for a value that contains and certain word and then reverse it. Here is the code I have:

```
msg = '{"company": "Happy, Inc.", "agent": "007"}' 
message = json.loads(msg)

for k , v in message.items():
        if not k.startswith("_"):
            if 'Happy' in v:
                message[k] = v[::-1]
print (json.dumps(message))
```

This reverses the string containing Happy but also reverses the tuples producing this:

```
{"agent": "007", "company": ".cnI ,yppaH"}
```

anyone know a way to just reverse the string without reversing the tuples as well?

**I'm teaching myself python and this is my first program using it

Comment: Which tuples?  If you mean the sorting in the dictionary, it can't be done.  Dictionaries are not sorted.

Comment: `reverses the tuples` what do you mean?

Comment: also, json objects are not sorted either. a certain representation does not guarantee the order of the keys (as there is no order).

Comment: I want it to output like this: {"company": ".cnI ,yppaH" ,"agent": "007" }

Comment: ["It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of *key: value* pairs..."](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to preserve the order of the keys in the JSON, you can parse it into an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead:

```
>>> message = json.loads(msg, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
>>> message["company"] = message["company"][::-1]
>>> message
OrderedDict([(u'company', u'.cnI ,yppaH'), (u'agent', u'007')])
>>> json.dumps(message, sort_keys=False)
'{"company": ".cnI ,yppaH", "agent": "007"}'
```

Comment: I won't actually know what the json string is I just wrote it that way for testing.  I have to write a function that accepts a json string  and searches for a "keyword" to reverse the string. It will be a message service and will have to push the modified message onto a queue to later be retrieved

Comment: @mbear Sure, I know, it's just an example.

Comment: To clarify, the order of the keys in a regular dictionary is not guaranteed and, in general, will not be in the same order that you enter them. The purpose of `OrderedDict` is to retain the order that you supply the keys. However, if the order that you supply the keys is of importance, you may want to rethink your algorithm and/or data structure. There is definitely a place for `OrderedDict` but there is a reason that it is not the default implementation (mainly hashing efficiency and little benefit from ordering in most implementations).